# How to check if two dates are in different months

Tags: php

I need to be sure that two dates are in different months, 
I tryed this wat but I get a bad result

```
$to_date = "2015-01-31";
$from_date = "2015-02-01";

$date1 = date_create($to_date);
$date2 = date_create($from_date);

$interval = date_diff($date1,$date2);

$elapsed['days'] = $interval->format('%a'); 
$elapsed['months'] = $interval->format('%m');


------------------- alternative method 
$month0 = date('n',$to_date);
$month1 = date('n',$from_date);
$elapsed['month_diff']=$month1-$month0;

-----------------------------
print_r($elapsed); 

Array ( [month_diff] => 0 [days] => 1 [months] => 0 )
```

Any tip?

Comment: @pkachhia Nope! Difference between January 1st and 31st is 30 but both days are in one month. Difference between January, 31st, and March, 1st is less than 30 but these days are in different months.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `getdate` function. This function returns array with information about date. Example:

```
$to_date = "2015-01-31";
$from_date = "2015-02-01";

$date1 = getdate(strtotime($to_date));
$date2 = getdate(strtotime($from_date));
if($date1["mon"] !== $date2["mon"] {
   ...your code....
}
```

Comment: `!===` shouldn't this be `!==`?

Answer (score 2):

Second argument of `date` is a timestamp, not a string. So, you should use `strtotime` to get timestamp of your dates:

```
$month0 = date('n',strtotime($to_date));
$month1 = date('n',strtotime($from_date));
$elapsed['month_diff'] = $month1 - $month0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this one works fine

```
$dateA1 = date_parse($to_date);
$dateA2 = date_parse($from_date);

$elapsed['month_diff']=$dateA1['month']-$dateA2['month'];
```